# Wrong boolean returns for birthday calc

Tags: php, boolean

My task is to be able to the an someones birthday as an argument and return there age and whether or not its there birthday in this specific way

```
getBirthDate('09/06/1992'); // returns array('age' => 21, 'birthday' => true);
```

I can't get the booleans to work right because it always returns the age correctly but always returns the "birthday" as false no matter if its the right date or not.

```
<?php
function getBirthDate($birthdate) {
    $today =getdate();
    $day =array($today["mon"], $today["mday"]);
    $newBday = str_replace("/",",",$birthdate);
    $birthDate = explode(",",$newBday);
    $monthDay = array($birthDate["0"],$birthDate[1]);
    $compared = array_diff($day,$monthDay);

    if ($compared === "") {
        $age = ($today["year"]-$birthDate["2"]);

        $dateArray = array( "age" => "$age", "birthday" => "True");
        return print_r ($dateArray);        
    }
    else {
        if ($monthDay[0] < $day[0]) {
            $age = (($today["year"]-$birthDate["2"])-1);
            $dateArray = array( "age" => "$age", "birthday" => "Fals");
            return print_r($dateArray); 
        }
        else {
            $age = (($today["year"]-$birthDate["2"]));
            $dateArray = array( "age" => "$age", "birthday" => "False");
            return print_r($dateArray); 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is that `dd/mm/yyyy`, or `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: Hey! If any answer here is helpful to you, you should select it as accepted. That is done [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png). I do this comment because it seems you have make several questions, but you have never selected an answer, even when you have got helpful answers. That is a bit rude.

Answer (score 1):

Why not change your code completely?

```
function getBirthDate($birthdate) {
    return array(
       'age'=>intval(substr(date('Ymd') - date('Ymd', strtotime($birthdate)), 0, -4)),
       'birthday'=>(date('md') === date('md', strtotime($birthdate)))
    );
}
```

I do not know your server's locale settings (d-m-Y or m-d-Y) but for portable code you should give $birthdate in ISO order (Y-m-d).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `array_diff` always returns an array. So `$compared === ""` always fails. When you use `count($compared) === 0` or `empty($compared)` instead, it works.

Also if I may suggest another edit. I would save those results in variables and create the result array at the end of the function. This way, when you want to change the way the result is presented later, you only have to edit one part of the code instead of three.

```
if (empty($compared)) {
    $age = ($today["year"]-$birthDate["2"]);
    $birthday = "true";        
}
else {
    if ($monthDay[0] < $day[0]) {
        $age = (($today["year"]-$birthDate["2"])-1);
        $birthday = "false";
    }
    else {
        $age = (($today["year"]-$birthDate["2"]));
        $birthday = "false";
    }
}
$result = array("age" => $age, "birthday" => $birthday);
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your comparison for `array_diff` is incorrect. You are trying to compare an array to a string. If you wish to check if an array has no values the best course of action would be one of the following ways.

```
count($compared) === 0
```

or

```
empty($compared)
```